# .htaccess and Wordpress - subdirectories not rewriting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am hosting multiple domains on a single hosting account. One of the domains is using Wordpress and in a subdirectory (/foo), while the other is in the main directory. I have successfully changed the root .htaccess file to rewrite the main page of the Wordpress site to the correct domain, but the subsequent pages for the Wordpress site are not rewriting.

```
Example: foo.com (Wordpress site) 
         bar.com (other site in root)
```

bar.com/foo is being shown correctly as foo.com....however bar.com/foo/page1 is not rewriting and is being shown as is (instead of foo.com/page1). I am looking for a rewrite and not a redirect. The .htaccess code I'm using in the root folder is below. I haven't changed the default .htaccess file created by Wordpress in bar.com/foo. Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foo/$1 [L]
```

Comment: **however bar.com/foo/page1 is not rewriting and is being shown as is (instead of foo.com/page1)**. I don't see any rules that affect `bar.com/foo/page1`, why would it show as anything else?

Comment: I am not very familiar with .htaccess rules. How would I rewrite those pages as well?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I rewrite those pages as well?

If you want requests for `bar.com/foo/page1` to show up as `foo.com/page1` in the address bar, you need a redirect (not an internal rewrite like you have above. It would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ http://foo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```